# How do I embed one SharePoint site page into another?

Tags: 2010, web-part, wiki-pages

In SharePoint 2010, I would like to insert the content from a site page into a column on other site pages, so those pages have a common column.  Think of it like an includes page on an HTML site.

I know how to do this with lists, etc. by inserting a Web Part, but I can't figure out how to insert the content of a site page.  The Page Viewer Web Part includes all of the headers and navigation, so that's not what I'm looking for.  I just want to insert the content of one page into another one.

I don't need to mass modify every page in the library, or (necessarily) create a custom template with this content in one column.  I'd just like to know whether it's possible and how to do do it on specific pages.  I'm currently using SharePoint Foundation, with plans to upgrade.  And please feel free to suggest a better way to do this.

Comment: Related question for Sharepoint Online "modern": https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/310564/how-to-include-content-of-one-page-in-another-page-in-sharepoint-online-modern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some additional searching led to the answer to this question.  To embed one SharePoint page into another, do the following:

1. Create your shared content page
2. On the page where you want to insert the shared content, add a column by Editing the page and then clicking Text Layout.
3. Go to Insert on the Ribbon and click Site Pages.
4. Edit the Site Pages web part (which is list of all pages at this point).
5. Under Toolbar Type (on List Views) choose 'No Toolbar.'
6. Under Appearance, change the Chrome to 'None.'
7. Click Edit Current View and check Wiki Content.  Uncheck all other columns.
8. Under Filter, change the Column drop down to Wiki Content and change contains to some unique text in your page.
9. Under Tablular view, uncheck the box to 'Allow individual item checkboxes.'
10. Under style, choose 'Newsletter, no lines'.

That should be it!

Also, you're probably better off going to to the Site Pages itself and creating a custom view with the above parameters.  Then it's easier to drop into various pages without having to make all changes every time.

I like the fact that with this method, you can update your shared page and it updates everywhere.  Good stuff.

Comment: Thanks @Carl. Do you know how this can be done in SP 2013?

Comment: I'm going on memory, but I'm 90% sure that's with SP 2013.  I only worked with SP 2010 for a little while, and I don't think I did this in that version.

Comment: WOW you have to be kidding me!  All this just to display a page as a sub page.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it's a bit closer:

Try appending `?IsDlg=1` to the URL (or `&IsDlg=1` if the URL already has a query string) when using the Page Viewer web part. You'll end up with a horisontal bar along the top but that might be ok for your requirements.