# How to include content of one page in another page in Sharepoint Online (modern)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, embedded, reusable-content

I am quite new to Sharepoint and I would like to create reusable building blocks.
Lets say I create a modern Page A in Sharepoint Online and include some contact persons (created using People WebPart).

In other Pages B, C, ... I want to insert Page A as a section.

If I change Page A, the updated content should automatically be shown on Pages B, C, ...
(I do not want to manually change 20 Pages if a single contact person changes.)

=> How to insert (content of ) Page A into Page B?

**a)** I tried to use the **Embed** Component to achieve this. However:

- I do not want to show the page title (was able to [remove the title using a workaround](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/how-to-hide-title-from-sharepoint-page/m-p/1265432)).
- I do not want to show the page "footer" (was not able to [hide likes](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/310577/how-to-disable-social-media-bar-for-site-collection-without-global-admin-rights) or skip it using the embed code).
- I do not want to use an **iframe** with fixed size. I want the overall layout to be **responsive**.

[image]

**b)** If I would use **List** elements, I would be restricted to text for the content (?). However, I would like to be able to use WebParts for the content of the resusable component.

**c)** I could create some **html** file as a **Document**, without Title and Likes etc. However, how to use WebParts inside this html file?

**=> What is the recommented way to create reusable components in Sharepoint Online "modern"?**

(In classic Sharepoint it seems there have been some features like Resusable Html, Content Editor and Page viewer. In JavaScript frameworks like react or vue, reusable components are kind of the core of everything.)

Would I need to create my own WebPart to insert another page? Is there some existing one? I am really surprised that Sharepoint does not seem to support this out of the box. I am still wondering, if I fundamentally miss something?

As an alternative approach:
[How to show and keep a page section for all sub sites while navigating?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/310578/how-to-show-and-keep-a-page-section-for-all-sub-sites-while-navigating)

**Related**:

- [How do I embed one SharePoint site page into another?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44757/how-do-i-embed-one-sharepoint-site-page-into-another)
- [In SharePoint 2013, how to embed one site page into another?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277996/in-sharepoint-2013-how-to-embed-one-site-page-into-another)
- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/is-there-a-way-to-embed-part-of-a-sharepoint-page/acce0881-db84-4fe2-bbc5-94c0e920f1a1
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/build-reusable-components-for-sharepoint
- [Best practices to improve search-ability in SharePoint Online and prepare for AI usage - how to handle meta data and alternative search terms?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/309995/best-practices-to-improve-search-ability-in-sharepoint-online-and-prepare-for-ai)
- https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/how-to-hide-title-from-sharepoint-page/m-p/1265432
- [How to disable Social media bar for site collection without global admin rights?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/310577/how-to-disable-social-media-bar-for-site-collection-without-global-admin-rights)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this out of the box, however you can try some workarounds depending on the type of data you want to display.

If your content is mostly text, you can use a List. You can show a specific list item on a page: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/is-there-a-way-to-embed-part-of-a-sharepoint-page/acce0881-db84-4fe2-bbc5-94c0e920f1a1

You can try to use Site Pages. Add a column to a page and insert Site Pages.

Otherwise if you need more control, you can make a custom WebPart. This needs some coding knowledge.