# How to disable Social media bar for site collection without global admin rights?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, modern-experience, administration, pnp-powershell

**A. Context of Access**

I do not have acces to the central sharepoint admin center but I am the owner of a site collection and I am site collection administrator:

[image]

I am able to connect to my site collection using pnp power shell:

```
Install-Module PnP.PowerShell -Scope CurrentUser
Connect-PnPOnline -url https://{domain}.sharepoint.com/sites/eis/ -Interactive
```

Furthermore, the command

```
Get-PnPSiteCollectionAdmin
```

returns my email address that I used to connect.

I also checked some [permission report](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/09/sharepoint-online-user-permissions-audit-report-using-pnp-powershell.html) and could not see something noticeable.

**B. Issue**

**However**, when running following command to remove the social bar / like feature:

```
Set-PnPSite -SocialBarOnSitePagesDisabled $true
```

I get

```
Error: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
```

**=> How can I troubleshoot and resolve that issue?**

- Are there some commands that I cannot excute if I do not have global admin rights, even if the command is on site collection level?
- Is there some setting in the global admin center that could be used to give me the required access rights or install some missing, required dependencies/features?
- Is there an alternative way to disable the Social media bar without using the pnp shell?

[image]

**Related:**

- https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2022/10/18/disable-likes-views-save-later-modern-sharepoint-pages/
- https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/09/sharepoint-online-user-permissions-audit-report-using-pnp-powershell.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use below PnP PowerShell script to show or hide the social bar from SharePoint online modern experience site pages for individual SharePoint Site:

```
# SharePoint online site URL
$siteUrl = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter your SharePoint site URL (e.g https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/work)"

# Connect to SharePoint online site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Interactive

# Hide the social bar from SharePoint online modern site pages
Set-PnPSite -SocialBarOnSitePagesDisabled $true

# Show the social bar on SharePoint online modern site pages
Set-PnPSite -SocialBarOnSitePagesDisabled $false

# Disconnect SharePoint online connection
Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

Make sure to use the **Site Collection Administrator** account of respective SharePoint site (As it might not work with just owner/full control permissions).

You can also achieve it using SharePoint Online PowerShell or CLI for Microsoft 365. Check this article for more details:

[Enable or Disable the Social Bar (Like, Views, Save for later) for individual SharePoint sites](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/06/20/enable-or-disable-the-social-bar-like-views-save-for-later-for-individual-sharepoint-sites/)

Comment: Thank you for the hint to chec k the site collection admin. I am the site colleciton administrator (or at least I think so) and as already said, the command "Set-PnPSite -SocialBarOnSitePagesDisabled $true" does not work.

Comment: Can you confirm once if you are SCA for this particular site from "Site Permissions > Site Collection Administrators" section?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question accordingly.