# How to show and keep a page section for all sub sites while navigating?

Tags: navigation, contacts, reusable-content

If I use a hub site, I have a shared navigation bar that stays on top while I navigate through the linked pages:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-up-your-sharepoint-hub-site-e2daed64-658c-4462-aeaf-7d1a92eba098#bkmk_hubsitebasicsforsiteowners

[image]

Similarly, I would like to show a shared side bar for all pages, including some custom content, e.g. contact persons.

How can I achieve that in Sharepoint Online modern?

Or, as an alternative, how can I put the content of an *.aspx page on all that sides? (If I want to change a contact, I only want to do it once.):

[How to include content of one page in another page in Sharepoint Online (modern)?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/310564/how-to-include-content-of-one-page-in-another-page-in-sharepoint-online-modern)